# How to execute test case in Azure Devops using Azure DevOps Services REST API?

Tags: rest, azure-devops, restsharp

I want to create test run in Azure devops through code which will execute my automated test case on the Agent/machine.

For this I tried using Rest API (Details are here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) for this. I have used RestSharp to consume these Rest APIs.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}");
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password);

var request = new RestRequest("_apis/test/runs?api-version=1.0", Method.POST);
            request.AddJsonBody(new RunResponce()
            {
                name = "OnDemandTestRun " + DateTime.UtcNow,
                plan = new Plan() { id = "9" },
                pointIds = new string[] { "3" },
                automated = true,
                dtlTestEnvironment = new DtlTestEnvironment() { id = "vstfs://dummy" },
                filter = new Filter() { sourceFilter = "*.dll", testCaseFilter = "" },
            });
            var response = client.Execute(request);
            var dserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
            var jsonResp = dserializer.Deserialize<RunResponce>(response);
            string id = jsonResp.id;

            request = new RestRequest("_apis/test/runs/" + id + "?api-version=1.0", Method.PATCH);
            request.AddJsonBody(new RunResponce()
            {
                build = new Build() { id = "4" },
                releaseEnvironmentUri = "vstfs:///ReleaseManagement/Environment/29",
                releaseUri = "vstfs:///ReleaseManagement/Release/22"
            });
            client.Execute(request);
```

This code creates test run but it doesn't trigger a test case on the respective machine. It keeps test run in 'In Progress' state.

Comment: You should trigger a release from a pipeline in order to get that automated test running. Otherwise, your test run will be created and your test gets to put as In progress, but nothing will happen until that release is triggered to run the test.

Comment: follow these [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#start-a-release) and add the proper code into your solution. Let me know if it works.